# How to allow request invalid characters in uploaded file name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, security, web-config

I have the following error when a user tries to upload a file with invalid characters in the file name (e.g. "John&#39;s Test.pdf").

> A potentially dangerous Request.Files value was detected from the client (filename="John&#39;s Tests.pdf").

I tried adding `ValidateInput(false)` to the controller action and `AllowHtml` to the model property but it doesn't work. Adding `requestValidationMode="2.0"` to the httpRuntime section in the Web.config file works but I don't want to change the validation mode.

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
```

How can I allow invalid characters in file names or is there a way to remove invalid characters before the ASP.NET validation is triggered?

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult UploadTicketAttachment(UploadTicketAttachmentModel model)
{
    ...
}

public class UploadTicketAttachmentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public IList<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
}
```